# How display ContentPage asynchronously in a MainPage?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I would like to display my page's contents asynchronously because it took a little time to be displayed

How the code works :

I have a main page named `MainPage`. In this main page, I am only changing  the content by display other page in it

How I change the content of my MainPage : I click on the button of the page that I want to display. For `instande "OnMyWords","OnTest" or "OnListFriend"`

Here is my  App.xaml.cs I have :

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

Here is my MainPage.xaml.cs :

```
ListFriend friendPage;
MyLeafNews newsPage;
View Testview;
View Friendview;

 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
     public MainPage() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            friendPage = new ListFriend();
            Friendview = friendPage.Content;
            MainView.Content = HomeView.Content;
        }

 string MyPageName = "home";
 public void OnMyWords(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyPageName = "home"; 
     MainView.Content = HomeView.Content;
}


bool resetTest = true; // pour garder la page test chargé
public void OnTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (MyPageName == "test")
            {

                var page = new TestWordsPage();
                MainView.Content = page.Content;               
                Testview = page.Content;
                resetTest = false;

            }
            else
            {   
                  MainView.Content = Testview;
            }    
}

        
public void OnListFriend(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyPageName != "friendList")
        {
           MainView.Content = Friendview;
           MyPageName = "friendList";
        }
        else
        {
            Friendview = page.Content;
             MainView.Content = page.Content;

        }
  }
}
```

Here is my  MainPage.xaml:

```
 <ContentView     IsVisible="True"  x:Name="MainView"   >
  <!-- is Empty because I fill it with other pages content -->
</ContentView>

 <ContentView   IsVisible="False"  x:Name="HomeView"   >
 <!-- Has many stuff here -->
 </ContentView>


<StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >
        
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnMyWords"  />
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>


<StackLayout   Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >

<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTest"  />
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

</StackLayout>

<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnListFriend"  />
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Please avoid putting tags in title when it is not necessary [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: What is your actual question?  Why are you creating entire pages (presumably these are ContentPages) if you are only displaying their Content property in your existing page?  If this is what you want then you should be using ContentView instead of ContentPage.  If you are trying to make your UI more responsive, then create the new views ahead of time instead of when the user pushes the button.  Or display all of the content on the page and toggle the visibility based on button clicks.

Comment: I want to display my content view more quickly, The way I  have done took a little time

Comment: @Jason I am creating an entire page because the MainPage contain button Menu so I want to change pages when I hit a button menu by changing the content

Comment: if you want it to be faster, do what I suggested: 1) use ContentView, not ContentPage for the "sub" pages, 2) pre-load the content instead of creating them on demand, 3) try toggling the visibility instead of dynamically loading them

Comment: thanks but how will i manage pages that need to be load, for instance in testpage, it needs to be load dynamically as it read information from other page

Comment: and my pages have xaml.cs file too not onlly xaml ( for instance test.xaml and test.xaml.cs)

Comment: @hugo I suggest you can consider to use Navigation to do.